# In javafxports where should the ANDROID_SDK path point to?

Tags: android, path, javafx, build-error

I have been getting some errors about the android sdk path being invalid so I was wondering where the path should point to?

Comment: try to give path till sdk folder like -PANDROID_SDK=C:\Users\Jolly\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the javafxports jfxmobile plugin, the gradle property that points to your Android SDK location is called ANDROID_HOME and can be configured in two ways:

1. As a gradle property (https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html)
2. As a system environment variable with the same name: ANDROID_HOME

The gradle property takes precedence over the system environment variable.